# Problem with customizing footer

Tags: header-footer

What is the problem with this code `\def\thepage{{\em Submitted to DAC 2014} \hfill \rm Page \arabic{page} of 6}` ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code. It depends on where you use it or what you do with it. Can you answer that question?

Comment: You want to hard code the number of total pages... ???? There is a package for that. `\usepackage{lastpage}`

Answer (score 5):

`\thepage` gives the value of the counter `page`. It is not advisable to redefine `\thepage` and it is wrong IMO (*don't do it*). You will be messing with the page numbers. A proper way will be as the following:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,heightrounded,headheight=16pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}         
\usepackage{lipsum}           
\usepackage{lastpage}         


\fancypagestyle{mypage}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[L]{\emph{Submitted to DAC 2014}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mypage}   % activate page style
\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```

[image]